# Can't display images from models when debug=false

Tags: django, image, debugging, model

I have asked another question about the issue of displaying images from models. and It was because I didn't add media url to urlpatterns. But it turns out that it only works when I set debug=true in settings file, when I set debug=false, I got 404 error again, any expert here to help ? I need to set debug=false for production

here my urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views as HomeViews


from django.conf.urls import include, url


from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
import os
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',HomeViews.index,name='home')
] 
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my settings file

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import django
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ws^pgf$%!=l8y#%^7anp$rl6*o4u9!86g-ba_uq9pcee=vc@13'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
     'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testimage.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'testimage.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Images(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views and template

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from home.models import Images
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    images = Images.objects.all()
    context = {
        'images':images
    }
    return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

template

```
{%for i in images %}
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{i.photo.url}}" alt="">
{%endfor%}
```

Here's the error when set debug=false:

```
[15/Feb/2021 13:17:05] "GET /media/20210129_205930.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179
[15/Feb/2021 13:17:05] "GET /media/20201227_111422.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 179
```

Please help me out. Many thanks !

Comment: Django does not serve static / media files in production (when `DEBUG = False`) because it is inefficient. Check [Serving static files in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production)

Comment: I've tried to set staticfile storage and I have no problems with static files when set DEBUG = False , but it throw out problems when I try to display images from models wihch is stored in media folder

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem
but I solve this problem using this code

```
pip install whitenoise
```

in settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

In urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    path('user_area/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('', include('user_area.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }), ]


python manage.py collectstatic
```

Follow this code you will solve your problems

Answer (score 0):

You should insert some `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in settings.py like :-

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

or Your website name :-

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your_website_name']
```